# XCODE pass a method as parameter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, parameters

I wan't to pass a method as a parameter to another method, so it know the method to call when ends running. Is it possible?

```
[self bringJSON:(NSString *)_passedValua:(NSObject *)anotherMethod];
```

Comment: Have you tried using selectors?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @Daniel mentioned in comments you can use [selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html) for that. Basic scheme will be the following:

```
// Method declaration - method accept selector as parameter
- (void) bringJSON:(NSString *)_passedValua toMethod:(SEL)anotherMethod];

// Method call - create selector from method name (mind the colon in selector - it is required if your method takes 1 parameter) 
[self bringJSON:jsonString toMethod:@selector(methodName:)];

// Implementation
- (void) bringJSON:(NSString *)_passedValua toMethod:(SEL)anotherMethod]{
   ...
   if ([target respondsToSelector:anotherMethod])
      [target performSelector:anotherMethod withObject:_passedValua];
}
```

Comment: awsome! tks a lot Vladimir and Daniel!

Comment: nice, honourable... thanx buddy :)